# Asterisk Cancel Transfer (atxfer)

Tags: asterisk

I'm using the Asterisk 13 AMI to start a atxfer. It works so far.
But how can I cancel the transfer action?

Example:
Bob calls Alice.
Then after some time talking, Alice starts an automated transfer to Charles.
Charles is not interested and but will not hang up, because of any reason.
How can Bob now hangup Charles and get Alice back?

If I'm using the disconnect feature (and the H dialplan option), Bob hangs up the call with Charles but does not get Alice back.
Bob then has an ongoing silent call and Alice still listens to the MOH.
If one of both hangs up, the other call hangs up automatically.

Which feature or feature code is needed to get Alice back?
Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Either by dtmf-ing *1 (Usually *2 to make the transfer, check in features.conf) or bridge the original channels manually. The "Atxfer" action actually sends dtmf internally.

You might want to take a peek at the "t" and "T" flags of the Dial application as they decide who can dtmf to a specific channel.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Dial

Btw: Atxfer stands for attended transfer.